# ssh Gitea on AWS EC2 when the AWS instance is not encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, debian, gitea

I'm new to encryption and SSH.

My AWS instance is currently running without encryption (only HTTP) because I don't have a public domain.

I'd like to install Gitea and enable SSH on it. Is this possible?
If so, could you provide any articles or resources?

The tutorials I've found so far all assume the use of a public domain.

Thank you.